# Django paginator not showing anything

Tags: django, pagination, django-templates

Django paginator not showing anything 
no error . but still result is none .

```
def question(request):
    objects = ['john', 'paul', 'george', 'ringo']
    paginator = Paginator(objects, 2)
    pList = paginator.page(1).object_list
    return render(request, 'app/question_list.html', { 'pList ': pList , 'objects':objects})
```

and html

```
<tbody>
{% for name in pList %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ name }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

now the page should have a list of names but instead 
it has nothing it acts like empty list . i checked page number , range etc everything is right ex:

```
<tbody>
{% for name in objects %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ name }}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

object are rendered fine but the issue is with Paginator do not know what i am missing .

Using python 2.7 with django 1.10 on Window 10

Comment: Have you tried `print pList` from the view?

Comment: yes i did printed it is show the right result . but not showing in template . i also check the type it is fine